What is this small capsule found behind my boiler?
I found this small capsule labeled

0.5560HFDDanfoss

behind my boiler after routine service.   It appears to be empty.  It's pictured here with a Sharpie for scale.  What is it?


The answers are all consistent and likely correct.  Just a comment - save this (at least the lid), so the next time service needs to be performed, you already have the info on what nozzle is needed rather than trying to get it off the nozzle itself.

I would, but don't know anything about heating and we just pay an annual maintenance contract.  Happy to assume they know what to use.  Good advice tho

It is a container that once contained a nozzle for the oil burners.

Danfoss is the brand
0.55 refers to the gallons of fuel per hour
60 degrees refers to the spray angle
HFD refers to the spray pattern and filter (H=hollow F=double filter)

Reference:
https://assets.danfoss.com/documents/latest/108094/AI025586458679en-US0101.pdf

A fast search says it is an oil burner nozzle. that is just a container to protect the nozzle from damage.
It either fell behind or was left.

A bit of web-searching on "danfoss 60 degree hfd" leads to here:
Oil Nozzles, HFD, 0.55 gal/h, 2.13 kg/h, 60 °, Hollow on the Danfoss website. Looks like a container for the nozzle on a n oil burner.
